# Adding value to ng-model on click of a list item

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a textbox

```
<input ng-model="meetingData.client.ClientName" id='txtClient'
                     placeholder="Add new client"  type="text">
```

and a list of items.

How can i set the the value of the text box to the value in the list item that I clicked on?

```
 <div class="item" ng-click="meetingData.client.ClientName = {{client.ClientName}}"
         ng-repeat="client in clients">
            <div class="lstClients">
                {{client.ClientName}}
            </div>
        </div>
```

I attempted the above but doesn't give the intended result.
Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try without {{ }}

```
<div class="item" ng-click="meetingData.client.ClientName = client.ClientName"
     ng-repeat="client in clients">
        <div class="lstClients">
            {{client.ClientName}}
        </div>
    </div>
```